# SQL Error: ORA-30556: either functional or bitmap join index is defined on the column to be modified

Tags: oracle, alter-table

When m trying to alter a column length of my table, then I get the following Oracle error:

```
 SQL Error: ORA-30556: either functional or bitmap join index is defined on the column to be modified
 30556. 00000 -  "either functional or bitmap join index is defined on the column to be modified"
 *Cause:    An ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN was issued on a column on which
            either a functional index or bitmap join index exists.
 *Action:   Drop the functional or bitmap join index before attempting to modify the column.
```

How we can alter our column size?

Comment: "*How we can alter our column size?*"- Drop the functional or bitmap join index before attempting to modify the column.

Comment: But we can not drop those indexes bcz they are critical in the prod.

Comment: You can add them again after modifying the column size...

Comment: in local i can do that ....but after delivering in prod its not easy...so is there any single query through which we can achieve this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to drop the index and alter the column size and then again create the index.

We have an alternate way in Oracle and that's the following:

1. First Disable the index. (ex: `ALTER INDEX index_cust ON CUSTOMER DISABLE`)
2. Then alter the column size of Customer table
3. Then Enable the index. (ex: `ALTER INDEX index_cust ON CUSTOMER REBUILD`)

**Note : And this is valid only for functional indexes**

Comment: This didn't work for me. I was still getting error ORA-30556 after disabling the indexes. After I dropped them, I could alter the column to a bigger size.

Comment: I tried this on Oracle 11.2 and found that it did not work. What release does it work on ?

Comment: Also does not work with Oracle 12.2

Comment: Does not work on 19.0 even. Any other solution?

Comment: This solution does not work. Have seen this error for several different functional indexes in different DB versions, and the only thing that works is to drop the functional index before table alteration, and to create it again.